# $c_{00}^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I met such a problem in functional analysis: I was asked to prove that $c_{00}^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_1$, with the aid of the fact that $c_0^*$ is isomorphic to $\ell_1$. (Here $c_0^*$ is the space of complex sequences converging to $0$ and  $c_{00}^*$ is the space of complex sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms.)

I had no idea how to make use of the given fact, but I guess that this is a classical example. Can anyone give me some hint? thanks!

Comment: The dual of the completion of a space is the dual of the original space.

Comment: @teddy thank u very much for editting!

Comment: you're welcome! @tooweaktolearnmathematics

Comment: @AshwinTrisal thanks! and a further question: where can I find the proof of the given fact that $c_0^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_1$? (our notes and lectures contain too few concrete examples...)